# Move a list to the next tab on click a button using tab layout

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

I have a recycler view on one tab. I am trying to move the recyclerview to the next tab when the user clicks on the next button as shown below. Im having to add the code move on the adapter class. Hence, below is the code for the adapter class. Any idea on how to move the recyclerview to the next tabs (ongoing + finished)

[image: UI]

code

```
public class recyclerKanbanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<kanbanItems> kanlist;
    Context context;
    public recyclerKanbanAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<kanbanItems>kanbanList)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.kanlist=kanbanList;
    }

    public recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemkanban,parent,false);
        return new recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull recyclerKanbanAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        kanbanItems kanban = kanlist.get(position);
        holder.contractorName.setText(kanban.getContractorName());
        holder.Duration.setText(kanban.getDuration());
        holder.taskName.setText(kanban.getTaskName());
        holder.btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                kanlist.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), kanlist.size());
            }
        });
        holder.btn_Move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //struggling to implemene the move button

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return kanlist.size();
    }
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        EditText taskName,Duration,contractorName;
        ImageButton btn_Delete;
        ImageButton btn_Move;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            btn_Move=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
            btn_Delete=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
            taskName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTaskName);
            Duration=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDuration);
            contractorName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContractor);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to move the recyclerview? I think you don't see any list when you go to the other tabs. Is that true?

Comment: they are tasks. once a task is started you move it to the next tab (ongoing) and once it is completed, u move it to (finished).  Yes because I have not implemented the next button. tried a few ways all failed. Do you have any idea on the steps required on move it.

Comment: By **next button** you mean that right arrow image button in the list item?

Comment: yes. it will send the task to the next tab

Comment: I see. Let me say you that the way of you think is not correct. You don't have to move any view to anywhere. This is all about managing the data. I don't know where your data is maintained, if you use a database for example; when you mark any item as finished you can query only the data that is marked as finish from database every time the user hits the finished tab.

Comment: for now i'd like it bo be static. so it is taking data in an arraylist. Hence how can i move the data in different column?

Comment: Well in this case you can implement `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener` to know when the user changed the tab. You can have 3 separate lists for each tab let's say; `listTodo`, `listOngoing` and `listFinished`. For instance; if the next button is pressed in **TODO** tab, remove this item from the `listTodo` list and add it to the `listOngoing` list. When the tab has changed to **ON GOING** tab, you set the adapter's list to `listOnGoing`. And the same procedure for *from ongoing to finished*. Does it make sense?

Comment: can you provide a reference to do this. eg YT or android developer?

Comment: What does YT means? Well you can have a look at the [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout) API reference, or you may want to have a look at [Tabs - Material Design](https://material.io/components/tabs/android) implementation guide, alternatively you may want to see this [Swipe Views with Tabs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2) guide. Or if you look for an example specific to your case I can make an example if you have time since I am very busy.